# WatiN IE browser and local javascript files using file:/// protocol

Tags: c#, nunit, internet-explorer, watin

I'm currently using WatiN to run some javascript unit tests however everything works fine if I initialise the WatiN IE browser like this:

```
Browser browser = new IE("http://localhost/Project/tests.hyml");
```

However, as soon as I try to initialise the browser with a file uri, i.e.:

```
Browser browser = new IE("c:\\\\Projects\\Project\\tests.html");
```

or

```
Browser browser = new IE("file:///C:/Projects/Project/tests.hml");
```

The javascript appears to fail to load.  I manually tested those file names and the tests work fine (after setting the Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security -> Allow Active Content...).

Is perhaps WaitN ignoring that Allow Active Content Setting?  Has anyone encountered this? Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Guido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the URL should be file://C:\Projects\Project\tests.html

Two slashes after the file:, and backslashes from there on.  Also, you typo-ed the file extension.

Comment: Wow that was easy, Thanks heaps